# Trouble using the com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog<T>

Tags: javafx, mobile, dialog, gluon

I need text input from my user in my gluon app. So I am using the `com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Dialog<T>` like shown below.

```
        Dialog<String> dialog = new Dialog();
        dialog.setResult("");
        com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField textField = new com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField("");
        textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                dialog.setResult((String) newValue);
            }
        });
        dialog.setContent(textField);
        Button ok = new Button("OK");
        ok.setOnAction(ev -> {
            dialog.hide();
        });
        dialog.getButtons().add(ok);
        String name = dialog.showAndWait().get();
```

When the *ok button* is pressed or when I press somewhere outside the dialog the app freezes. It works on desktop as expected can be mentioned. How can I solve this on mobile?

The problem seem to be because that it is shown from a button side a `SidePopupView`

Comment: It works fine for me (Android and iOS). Can you post your versions (build.gradle)?

Comment: I updated to `com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0` from `com.gluonhq:charm:4.4.1` and it solved the problem